# Entire table row clickable except when clicking element within a td with a .class

Tags: jquery, html-table

I've made entire rows in my table clickable. Within some of the columns there is show/hide functionality when you click a link for some data e.g.

```
<td>
    <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
...etc. etc...
    <li class="show-hide"><a href="#" class="show-hide">Show more</a></li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

Which basically just expands a ul from showing 3 li's to 10...

But because the entire table row is clickable, when I click 'Show more', it goes to the link of the row... and ignores the function of the show/hide.

So what I'd like to achieve is that when a user clicks the link with the class="show-hide" > then ignore the jQuery that sends the user to the link of the entire row...

jQuery to make row clickable

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

Comment: have you tried event.stopPropagation();

Comment: I'd need some advice on how to put that in context please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catch the event and read its properties. By this way you can identify what is you clicking right now.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function(event) {
        if(!$(event.target).hasClass('show-hide')) {
           window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
        }
    });
});
```

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/19ywsnh9/

Answer (score 2):

Use **event.stopPropagation()**, it will restrict parent event to call. please refer link : [When use event.stopPropogation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
    $(".show-hide").click(function (event) {            
        event.stopPropagation();
        // your logic here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind event to `li` except with class `.show-hide`:

```
$('.clickable-row li:not(.show-hide)').click(function () {
    window.document.location = $(this).closest('.clickable-row').data("href");
});
```

Comment: The entire row is clickable, not only `<li>`s

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude It's just matters where you bind event.

Comment: You are changing the behaviour of the logic with this code. Is not the same bind all the `<tr>`tag avoiding certain conditions, than remove that binding and add only in `<li>` tags, because all the remain space will not be clickable. I think this is not a good solution.